# Generating Python Client Library - for Android

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine

I am trying to Generate the Discovery Doc for the Python API I have developed and am following the guide here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/gen_clients#generating_for_android

I am confused as to what command-line they are referencing though. I was reading this googledrive presentation and it mentions a command-line tool bundled with the App Engine SDK, but I cannot seem to locate it.

https://googledrive.com/host/0B19L0O2pMOKjVUJBV0tEb0psVlU/#4

**What Endpoint command-line tool are they referencing?** I have located an endpoints "windows command script" type file bundled with the Java SDK but running it seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question: You can just use the cmd tool offered through Windows. There isn't a specific Endpoints Command Line Tool.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the python sdk you are looking for https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python

Comment: I have that installed, and up to date. I just don't see a Endpoints Command-Line tool that is being referenced in there Dev Guides.

Comment: The documentation uses endpointscfg.py to generate the client library

Comment: I see that, but when you run endpointscfg.py in the Python Intepreter it opens the console and than exits shortly after.